# C# How to modularly fill a list with floating point values via user input, calculate sum and average

Tags: c#

Mind you, I come from a C++ background and the instructor I have should be called an assignment proctor AT MOST. No instruction or guidance whatsoever. Now, is it possible that some kind person could assist me and help me figure out what I'm doing wrong and then explain(In durr durr language)how to fix it so that it compiles??? Here is the code and the errors. Got it down from 22 but these last 9 are killing me and it's now 3 a.m.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace P1_Wilson
{
 class P1_Wilson
  {

    float sum;
    float aver;
    int counter;
    static float FillNumber()//Declaration of method utilized to fill an array/list of                              floating point numbers.
     {
       int counter = 0;
       List<float> floatlist = new List<float>();
       char sentinel;
       Console.WriteLine("I would like you to now input a few floating point numbers.\n                           Enter q to quit.");
       Console.WriteLine("You have the option to quit now.\nWould you like to continue? \nEnter q to quit.");
       sentinel = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        while (sentinel != 'q')
         {
          Console.WriteLine("You have the option to quit now.\nWould you like to  continue?\nEnter q to quit.");
          sentinel = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
          Console.WriteLine("Then please input a floating point number.");
          floatlist[counter] = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine(floatlist[counter]));
          counter++;
          return floatlist;
          return counter;
         }

     }
    static float CalcSum(List<float> floatlist, int counter)//Declaration of method  used to add all entered numbers together and calculate the total sum.
     {
      for (; counter >= 0; counter--)
       {
        float sum = sum + floatlist[counter];
       }
       return sum; 
     }
    static float CalcAver(float sum, float aver, int counter)//Declaration of method used to calculate the average of numbers entered.
     {
      aver = sum / counter;
      return aver;
     }

    static void Main()//Where execution of program begins. Introduces user to program. Prompts for user input and calls all subservient methods.
     {
      FillNumber();
      CalcSum();
      CalcAver();
      Console.WriteLine("The total number of floating point numbers entered is:" +  counter); 
      Console.WriteLine("The total sum is:" + sum);
      Console.WriteLine("The average of the numbers entered is:" + aver);
      Console.ReadLine();
     }
  }
}
```

These are my errors: 9

Error 1 No overload for method 'ReadLine' takes 1 arguments 
Error 5 No overload for method 'CalcSum' takes 0 arguments 
Error 6 No overload for method 'CalcAver' takes 0 arguments 
Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'float'
Error 3 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'P1_Wilson.P1_Wilson.sum'
Error 8 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'P1_Wilson.P1_Wilson.sum'
Error 7 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'P1_Wilson.P1_Wilson.counter'
Error 9 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'P1_Wilson.P1_Wilson.aver'
Error 4 'sum' conflicts with the declaration 'P1_Wilson.P1_Wilson.sum'

I apologize if my one lame attempt at humor served more to anger instead of to kindly engender chuckles.

Comment: First off all, you defined CalcSum and CalcAver to take in parameters, but didnt pass any.

Answer (score 0):

Read your error messages one by one and fix them, for example :

- Error 1 No overload for method 'ReadLine' takes 1 arguments

  This error message is not ambiguous, specifically when Visual Studio should point you to the exact point in code where it occurs.

  In that case it is :

  ```
  Console.ReadLine(floatlist[counter]);
  ```

Please try to fix your errors one by one by carefully reading the error messages (and googling them if needs be) and come back if you struggle with a specific error or if you would like a code review when the code is running.